# Find graph colouring that minimises sum of weights of edges that share vertex colours

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-theory

Suppose we have a weighted complete graph with n vertices. We want to colour each vertex one of k colours. The cost of any colouring is the sum of the weights of all edges that connect vertices of the same colour.

For my use case, n will be around 20-50. For k = 2, 3 brute force worked fine, but I would ideally like a solution for any k. It is also the case that the graphs I'm dealing with have reasonable sparsity, but again, I would ideally like to solve the general case.

Comment: This problem contains graph coloring as a special case (if the graph is k-colorable, you can get zero weight), so it’s NP-hard and likely has the same difficulty to approximate as graph coloring.

Comment: A graph cannot be sparse and complete.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen The weights can be sparse (i.e. mainly zero). This is what I was referring to.

Comment: Can you please clarify in the question: do you need the best coloring, or good enough? Best isn't necessarily unique, especially for sparse weights, so do you want one or all?

Comment: Can we assume weights are non-negative?

Comment: A good enough colouring will do. And, yes, the weights are non-negative.

Answer (score 4):

A first start could be to throw this at a MIQP (Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programming) solver. It can be linearized into a MIP (that is what a solver like Cplex is doing automatically).

```
min sum( (arcs(i,j),c), w(i,j)*x(i,c)*x(j,c))   (sum over all arcs i<j and colors c)
subject to  sum(c, x(i,c)) = 1 for all nodes i
            x(i,c) in {0,1}
```

With 50 nodes, weights 25% dense, k=5 it took me a couple of seconds to solve to proven optimality (but can be much more depending on the data; many zero weights make the problem easier). k=3 is slightly more difficult with a run time between 30 and 60 seconds depending on the exact formulation.

The mathematical formulation of the linearization can be found [here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2022/01/a-different-coloring-problem.html).